# jQuery How to hide all span containing td in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hide

I have some rows in a table like the code below and I want after some seconds to hide the contents of `td`'s (i have filled them with text in a loop).
My sample code is this

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('span').each(function(index, el) {
      $(this).hide();//nothing happens
  });
}, 5000);


<tr>
  <span class="myspan"><td></td></span>
  <span class="myspan"><td></td></span>
  <span class="myspan"><td></td></span>
  <span class="myspan"><td></td></span>
</tr>
```

I tried using other ways too, like saving all `span`s to an array, or selecting the class and hiding it.

```
var arr=$('span');
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i].css('visibility','hidden');
}
```

but same thing happened. I want to be able to show and hide the contents of `td`'s when it's needed without hiding the border if it is possible

Comment: Look at your DOM; regardless of the HTML there will be no `<span>` elements in the DOM wrapping the `<td>` elements; it's invalid HTML: if you want a `<span>` in a `<table>`, that `<span>` must be wrapped in either `<td>` or `<th>`.

Comment: You can't have a `span` element as child node of a `tr` element and a `td` element can't have anything other than a `tr` element as parent node.

Comment: I wanted to be able to hide the contents of td and be able to show them again, that's because i thought this method. I tried many things with no success. Could you suggest something? :)

Comment: What contents are we talking about? Your example has blank `td`s. Also try putting the `span` elements inside the `td`s and not the other way around.

Comment: I fixed it as you told me.I found what the problem was after putting the span into td (the opposite was stupid, don't know why i did it ). In one of my attempts I was using `$('span).each({.....` instead of `$('td span).each({.....`. Now everything is working fine. Thank you guys

Comment: @Botimoo i mentioned that I was filling them in a code block above which was not in the question.

Comment: No need for `each` .... `$('td span').hide()` will hide them all

Comment: Why use spans to classify? You can use class in the td. It's like using classes to spanify... It doesn't make sense.

Comment: @RubyRacer I wanted to hide the content of td. Couldn't think anything else. When I was hiding the td, the borders were lost, so the table wasn't nice.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use any element in td tag from table.
otherwise browser convert your code to valid code.
output your HTML is like that in browser:

```
<body>
    <span class="myspan"></span>
    <span class="myspan"></span>
    <span class="myspan"></span>
    <span class="myspan"></span>
    <table>
        <tbody>
           <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</body>
```

you select span but there is no more td in your target span. SO your delect is false.

you have to change yor HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td><span class="myspan"></span></td>
  <td><span class="myspan"></span></td>
  <td><span class="myspan"></span></td>
  <td><span class="myspan"></span></td>
</tr>
```

now you can select it and do your function:

```
var arr=$('span');
arr.css('visibility','hidden');
```

or

```
var arr=$('span');
arr.hide();
```

later show yor it:

```
att.show();
```

you dont need for or any loop. just select your target and say ehat do you want to do. JQuery do it for each on in your selector (exactly like a loop)

Answer (score -1):

To hide all after 5 seconds, you can use the following code

```
setTimeout(function() {
 $('table tr span').hide(5000);
}, 5000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function() {
     $('table tr span').css('visibility','hidden');
 }, 5000);
```